# Synchronously stop a remote service with Powershell

Tags: services, powershell

I have a custom deployment script written in Powershell. This script needs to update a service on a remote machine, and as such, it first needs to stop it to be able to modify the executable files.

This seems to be a problem.

To synchronously stop a service, I can use `net stop servicename` or `stop-service servicename`. The problem is that these two commands are confined to the local machine.

To stop a service on a remote machine, I know I can use the `sc.exe` program:

```
sc.exe \\computername stop servicename
```

But this is asynchronous, so I can't really use it (well, `sleep 5` seems to do it, but that's rather dirty).

How can I synchronously stop a remote service using Powershell?

Comment: Run a loop that queries the service status every couple of seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Get-Service** returns a **ServiceController** object, which you can then use to manipulate the service. It doesn't matter whether it's local or remote.  I have the script below to stop the Spooler (Print Spooler) service and wait for it to stop, up to 5 seconds. I just added the -Name parameter to Get-Service, and I was able to stop the spooler on a remote server.

**Note:** Both servers in my case were Server 2008 R2. Your mileage may vary.

```
Set-StrictMode -Version "2.0"

[System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController]$service = Get-Service -Name "Spooler" -ComputerName "remote_server.domain.com"

[int]$waitCount = 5
do
{
    $waitCount--

    switch($service.Status)
    {
        { @(
        [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::ContinuePending,
        [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::PausePending,
        [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::StartPending,
        [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::StopPending) -contains $_ }
        {
            # A status change is pending. Do nothing.
            break;
        }

        { @(
        [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Paused,
        [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Running) -contains $_ }
        {
            # The service is paused or running. We need to stop it.
            $service.Stop()
            break;
        }

        [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Stopped
        {
            # This is the service state that we want, so do nothing.
            break;
        }
    }

    # Sleep, then refresh the service object.
    Sleep -Seconds 1
    $service.Refresh()

} while (($service.Status -ne [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Stopped) -and ($waitCount -gt 0))
```

There is also **Set-Service** that will accept a computer name parameter, but it does not seem to be able to stop a service if that service has dependent services.

Comment: It seems I don't have Powershell 2, but I was able to use `New-Object System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController -ArgumentList myservice, myserver` to get a handle. Also, I used the `WaitForStatus` method instead of looping with a sleep.

Comment: I am trying to param-atize that little script you have and wrapping it in a function.  However, When I add parameters I get a null parameter exception.

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell 2 added a lot of stuff for accessing remote computers with it.

Here's some useful cmdlets to look into (info from PowerShell's `get-help`):

`Enter-PSSession`:

> SYNOPSIS
>    Starts an interactive session with a remote computer.
>
> DESCRIPTION
>     The Enter-PSSession cmdlet starts an interactive session with a single remote computer. During the session, the commands that you type
>   run on the remote computer, just as though you were typing directly on
>   the remote computer. Youcan have only one interactive session at a
>   time.
>
> Typically, you use the ComputerName parameter to specify the name of the remote computer. However, you can also use a session that you
>   create by using New-PSSession for the interactive session.
>
> To end the interactive session and disconnect from the remote computer, use the Exit-PSSession cmdlet, or type "exit".

`New-PSSession`:

> SYNOPSIS
>   Creates a persistent connection to a local or remote computer.
>
> DESCRIPTION
>   The New-PSSession cmdlet creates a Windows PowerShell session (PSSession) on a local or remote computer.  When you create a PSSession, Windows PowerShell establishes a persistent connection to the remote computer.
>
> Use a PSSession to run multiple commands that share data, such as a function or the value of a variable. To run commands in a PSSession, use the Invoke-Command cmdlet. To use the PSSession to interact directly with a remote computer, use the Enter-PSSession cmdlet. For more information, see about_PSSessions.

`Invoke-Command`:

> SYNOPSIS
>   Runs commands on local and remote computers.
>
> DESCRIPTION
>   The Invoke-Command cmdlet runs commands on a local or remote computer and returns all output from the commands, including errors. With a single Invoke-Command command, you can run commands on multiple computers.
>
> To run a single command on a remote computer, use the ComputerName parameter. To run a series of related commands that share data, create a PSSession (a persistent connection) on the remote computer, and then use the Session parameter of Invoke-Command to run the command in the PSSession.

More info: [Hey, Scripting Guy! Tell Me About Remoting in Windows PowerShell 2.0](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/10/29/hey-scripting-guy-october-29-2009.aspx)

Comment: With PS2, you also have a `ComputerName` argument on `Get-Service`.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into something like [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx). It will execute the `net stop` on the remote machine, and will thus get the synchronous part, but it can be done remotely (that is the point of PsExec after all).

Comment: That might be a good idea, but I'd rather not have to install anything new on my own machine.

Comment: @zneak I hear that. Techie007's answer is the way to go then :)